# the output in reference of descriptor

Tags: python-3.x, descriptor

```
class C(object):  
    a = 'abc'  
    def __getattribute__(self, *args, **kwargs):  
        print("__getattribute__() is called")  
        return object.__getattribute__(self, *args, **kwargs)  
    def __getattr__(self, name):  
        print("__getattr__() is called ")  
        return name + " from getattr"  
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):  
        print("__get__() is called", instance, owner)  
        return self  
    def foo(self, x):  
        print(x)  


class C2(object):  
    d = C()  

>>>c2=C2()
>>>c2.d  
__get__() is called <__main__.C2 object at 0x000000000297BE10> <class '__main__.C2'>  
<__main__.C object at 0x000000000297BBA8>
```

I understant the result ,c2.d trigger the **get** method in class C.

```
def __get__(self, instance, owner):    
    print("__get__() is called", instance, owner)    
    return self
```

It print "**get**() is called", instance, owner and return self `<__main__.C object at 0x000000000297BBA8>`

```
>>> c2.d.a  
__get__() is called <__main__.C2 object at 0x000000000297BE10> <class '__main__.C2'>  
__getattribute__() is called    
'abc'
```

Why the result of c2.d.a  is not :

```
__get__() is called <__main__.C2 object at 0x000000000297BE10> <class __main__.C2'>    
<__main__.C object at 0x000000000297BBA8>      
__getattribute__() is called      
'abc'
```

Why the`return self` in the **get** method in class C  does not work? Why there is no <**main**.C object at 0x000000000297BBA8>  in the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<**main**.C object at 0x000000000297BBA8>

is not part of printing, it's the result of c2.d expression.

Comment: why it will be outputed in c2.d,it will not be outputed in c2.d.a ?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature you are using a shell. the result of an expression is meant to be printed.

Comment: why the result of  expression does not printed in c2.d.a?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature that is 'abc'

Comment: why there is no <__main__.C object at 0x000000000297BBA8> in c2.d.a? there is  <__main__.C object at 0x000000000297BBA8> in c2.d